# How to set 'Github' Pull request number in Travis Build Notification?

Tags: github, travis-ci

How to set Github Pull request number in Travis build notification? ex: git fetch origin +refs/pull/**822**/merge: (Pull Request)

I have made an integration between `Travis CI` and `GitHub` and planning to keep the PULL REQUEST number in Build notification like in Email. How to set this?

Note: I am not looking for TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST Number as this is increment of the pull requests coming from github to Travis.

Comment: Can you expand a little bit? What's "Travis build notification" exactly? If you're asking how to set job numbers on Travis: you can't.

Comment: What i mean i want to send Pull request number in Email notification to developers. I am getting the Pull request number from Travis but i want to keep pull request number in email notification.

Comment: The e-mail notification cannot be modified by the end-user.

Comment: Any other options to get the pull request number (Any Environment variable?) and send it in any notification method?

Comment: [PR number (or `"false`") is in `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Convenience-Variables)

Comment: TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST number will provide the pull request number starts from 1 but my GitHub pull request number will be different (As mentioned `git fetch origin +refs/pull/822/merge: (Pull Request)`. I want to take the Pull request number 822. Any option?

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of [CatLight build notifier](https://catlight.io) can show GitHub PR# in Travis notifications and on the dashboard.